# Creating a Coach Mark on Android

Tags: android

I am trying to create a coach mark for Android.

I want it to be absolutely full screen, and my app has an `ActionBar`. So, the solution suggested by Commons, which is basically inflate a FrameLayout after `setContentView(view);` does not work, because the `FrameLayout` would be below the `ActionBar`. And I want it full screen.

So, I took a screenshot of my screen and drew some coach marks with photoshop and created a .png file of it. I then load this png file with the following code:

```
public void onCoachMark(){
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_coach_mark);
        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);

        //for dismissing anywhere you touch
        View masterView = dialog.findViewById(R.id.parent);
        masterView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                preferences.edit().putBoolean("COACH_MARK_MAIN_SHOWN", true).commit();
            }
        });
        dialog.show();
    }
```

This works perfectly on my phone, but as we all know, we have thousands of Android models. With another model, this is how it looks like:

[image: http://s21.postimg.org/7989378tz/Screenshot_2013_07_05_13_18_03.png]

I have tried using the [ShowcaseView](https://github.com/Espiandev/ShowcaseView%E2%80%8E) project but, apparently, it does not work with ActionBar buttons. And I need that.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

Simply add this to your `onCoachMark` method:

```
dialog.getWindow().setLayout(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just think simply

Step 1: Open your main_activity layout file

Step 2: In the main_activity layout check Root Layout, If the Root Layout not start with FrameLayout, change it to FrameLayout.

Step 3: Converting from other layout to FrameLayout it may cause layout problem, you have to fix it. Step 4: Create another FrameLayout that will overlay top of your existing view.

```
Example:
<FrameLayout ...>

        .....
        ....
         <FrameLayout
         android:id="@+id/c_mark"
         .../>

</FrameLayout>
```

Step 5: Position your new FrameLayout by layout gravity. Example: android:layout_gravity="top|right"

Step 6: Hide that view by default

Step 7: Now in your Main Activity use this Id and play with property. Just custom design your c_mark FrameLayout set id and use it. Let me Give you example.

Let me Give you example.

Example: MainActivity.class

```
    FrameLayout coachMarkLayout = findViewById( R.id.c_mark);
    coachMarkLayout.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );

    FrameLayout messageBoxLayout = (FrameLayout) rootFrameLayout.getChildAt( 0 );
    LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) messageBoxLayout.getChildAt( 1 );

    Button skipButton = (Button) linearLayout.getChildAt( 0 );
    skipButton.setOnClickListener( v -> {
        rootFrameLayout.setVisibility( View.GONE );
    } );

    Button nextButton = (Button) linearLayout.getChildAt( 1 );
    nextButton.setOnClickListener( v -> {
        rootFrameLayout.setVisibility( View.GONE );
        // you can add second coarch mark here
    } );
```

main_activity.xml

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/c_mark"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
    android:visibility="gone">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="70dp">
        <include layout="@layout/layout_message_box"/>
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal">
        <include layout="@layout/layout_arrow"/>
    </FrameLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```